# Inject Map from command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm fairly new to spring so excuse me if this is a dumb question. When I try to launch a program I get the following error .

**java -jar target/rest-executor-1.0.jar rest.args={name:'nokia',id:'233'}**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restArgument': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'rest.args' in value "{rest.args}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:379)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)




    public class RESTArgument {

    @Value(Argument.SERVER_PORT)
    private int serverPort;

    @Value(Argument.SERVER_ADDRESS)
    private String serverAddress;

    @Value(Argument.APP_NAME)
    private String applicationName;

    @Value(Argument.RESOURCE_NAME)
    private String resourceName;

    @Value(Argument.REST_ARGS)
    private Map<String,String> restArgs;

    public RESTArgument() {
    }

    public int getServerPort() {
        return serverPort;
    }

    public String getServerAddress() {
        return serverAddress;
    }

    public String getApplicationName() {
        return applicationName;
    }

    public String getResourceName() {
        return resourceName;
    }

    public  Map<String,String> getRestArgs(){
        return restArgs;
    }
}
```

How can I inject a map from command line in my application ? My application will be invoked at run time so I can not use properties file .

Comment: Can you try something like this `-Drest.args="{\"name\":\"nokia\",\"id\":233}"`?

Comment: You save the day. It worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe passing a JSON map as a command line option is possible.
Properties passed through the command line should be passed as pairs in this form `--key="value"`.
So in your case you may try something like this:

```
java -jar target/rest-executor-1.0.jar --args.name="nokia" --args.id="233"
```

And then in your java code:

```
@Value("args.name")
private String name;

@Value("args.id")
private Integer id;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying . But there can be n key and values thats why I need a map .

Comment: If the values of these properties are environment specific, then I recommend having an application properties file for each environment and then you only need to specify the active profile when starting the application.